# Un bucle for de php no reconoce todos los indices

Tags: php, bucles, metodos

Este metodo recibe un arreglo conformado por objetos, busca verificar si que si el id del nuevo producto elegido ya esta en el arreglo y tratarlo en consecuencia, pero por alguna razon solo tiene en cuenta el primer indice para probar la condicion, pasando por alto todos los demas. No entiendo lo que pasa, porque anteriormente el foreach recorria todos los elementos con normalidad, pero conforme agregue las condiciones y el codigo, comenzo a fallar.

```
public function verificarProductos($datos_carrito){
            //EL FOR EACH SOLO RECORRE UNO DE LOS ELEMENTOS
                $id_producto = $this->id_producto;
                $datos =  $this->datos;
                $precio = $this->precio;
        
        
                foreach ($datos_carrito as $producto) {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($producto->id_producto . " comparado con " . $id_producto);
                    echo "</pre>";
                    if ($producto->id_producto == $id_producto) {
                        echo "producto en el carrito";
                        $producto->unidades = $producto->unidades + 1;
                        return $datos_carrito;
                    }else{
                        echo "producto NO en el carrito";
                        $producto = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                        JsonManager::set_json($producto);
                        #Esta de abajo, claramente es una funcion para convertir el json guardado dentro de la 
                        #sesion 'carrito' en un elemento utilizable.
                        $datos_session = JsonManager::decodificar();
                        $nuevoProducto = [
                            "id_producto" => $id_producto,
                            "precio" => $precio,
                            "unidades" => 1,
                            "objeto" => $datos
                        ];
                        #La esta funcion guarda todo en un arreglo con el todos los indices
                        #al mismo nivel.
                        $carrito = $this->guardarTodo($datos_session, $nuevoProducto);
                        return $carrito;
                    }
        
                }
                
                    
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el flujo de tu bucle foreach y cómo manejas la lógica de verificación. En el momento en que encuentras un producto que no coincide con el $id_producto, estás sobrescribiendo toda la variable $producto con $_SESSION['carrito']. Esto significa que, en el próximo ciclo del bucle foreach, estarás comparando todos los productos restantes con el primer producto de la sesión 'carrito'.

Podrias hacerlo asi:

```
public function verificarProductos($datos_carrito) {
    $id_producto = $this->id_producto;

    foreach ($datos_carrito as $index => $producto) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($producto->id_producto . " comparado con " . $id_producto);
        echo "</pre>";

        if ($producto->id_producto == $id_producto) {
            echo "producto en el carrito";
            $producto->unidades = $producto->unidades + 1;
            return $datos_carrito;
        }
    }

    // Si llegamos a este punto, significa que el producto no está en el carrito
    echo "producto NO en el carrito";
    
    // Recuperar el carrito de la sesión
    $datos_session = JsonManager::decodificar();

    // Crear un nuevo producto
    $nuevoProducto = [
        "id_producto" => $id_producto,
        "precio" => $this->precio,
        "unidades" => 1,
        "objeto" => $this->datos
    ];

    // Agregar el nuevo producto al carrito
    $carrito = $this->guardarTodo($datos_session, $nuevoProducto);
    
    return $carrito;
}
```

En este código, he eliminado la línea $producto = $_SESSION['carrito']; ya que no es necesario y puede causar el problema que estás experimentando. Además, he agregado un índice $index al bucle foreach, lo que permite acceder a cualquier producto en cualquier posición del arreglo $datos_carrito. Ahora, el código debería manejar correctamente todos los productos en el carrito.